# How would I go about making the background image repeatedly scroll vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can this be done using just HTML5 and CSS3 or do I need to use JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: yes / no . these would be the answers. this is not a question for stackoverflow. read here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-repeaty try this

Comment: [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)

Comment: `background-repeat: repeat-y;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: By scrolling vertically repeatedly do you mean having it animated?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css property: background-repeat: repeat-y;

Here is an example:

```css
body {
  background-image:url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12005/starsolid.gif');
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: top;
}

h1, p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>H1 heading</h1>
  <p>This is the content</p>
</body>
```